# C File Descriptor is returning -1 on open

Tags: c, file-descriptor

Embarrassingly simple question, but I can't seem to open a new file for writing using a file descriptor. Every variation I've tried returns `-1`. What am I missing? This is how you initialize a file using file descriptors, correct? I can't find documentation that states otherwise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
  int fd;
  mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;
  fd = open ("/home/CSTCIS/sample.dat", O_WRONLY, mode);
  printf("%d\n", fd);
}
```

perror() prints `open: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Check `errno`: what does `perror` say?

Comment: Try `perror("open")` before the `printf` and see what it says.

Comment: Or add `<errno.h>` and `<string.h>` to your headers and use `printf("%d (%d: %s)\n", fd, errno, strerror(errno));` in place of your current `printf()`.

Comment: Before doing all that, you may want to check the file permissions on /home/CSTCIS/sample.dat ... if you don't have write permission, it _should_ return -1

Comment: @technosaurus: But it would report EPERM and not ENOENT if it was a permissions problem.  It would report ENOTDIR if `/home/CSTCIS` existed but was a file, not a directory.  Etc.

Comment: I use vim and tmux, and even though I have disabled the auto-integer-increment shortcut in VIM with a nop, it still sometimes work.
While I was switching between tmux windows, a null terminator of the filename I was `open`ing has increased to '\1'. It took me 1.5 days to figure out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting [pubs.opengroup.org](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html),

> Upon successful completion, the [`open`] function shall open the file and
>   return a non-negative integer representing the lowest numbered unused
>   file descriptor. Otherwise, **-1 shall be returned and errno set to
>   indicate the error. No files shall be created or modified if the
>   function returns -1**.

To check what the problem is with the `open()` statement, just write:

```
perror("open");
```

before the `printf()` statement.

OP has found a solution:

> The `open()` command works if `O_CREAT` flag is included.
>
> ```
> fd = open ("/home/CSTCIS/sample.dat", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, mode);
> ```

Comment: perror() prints open: No such file or directory. I've tried both sample.dat as well as the full path name and neither seem to work. Must the file must be created by some other means prior?

Comment: @user1185790: You don't have to pre-create the file by some other means.  Does the directory `/home/CSTCIS` exist? Does `/home` exist?  It is pretty safe that `/home` exists, but it is less certain about `/home/CSTCIS`.  Remember, file names (and therefore directory names too) are case-sensitive on most systems.  I have a `/home` directory without `/home/CSTCIS` in it; I get ENOENT when I try to create the file in the non-existent directory.

Comment: Yes, I used `pwd` to obtain them. I tried without the path (just the filename) and even that didn't work. I tried on a remote machine as well as my own.

Comment: @user1185790: If you go to the shell, can you run `cp /dev/null /home/CSTCIS/appendectomies.for.fun` or some such file name that doesn't yet exist.  Does that work?

Comment: `touch test.txt` works in both locations. I know I have rights in both - they're my own folders.

Comment: When I do `touch sample.dat` and then run it I then get a return of `3`. For some reason it expects it to be initialized.

Comment: @user1185790 If the problem has been solved, you could accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

When we are using the `open() function` , we can open the file which is already present in our file structure.

If we want to create a new file, then we can use the `O_CREAT` flag in open()
function or we can use the `creat()` function like this.

```
   mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;
   fd = open ("/home/CSTCIS/sample.dat", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, mode);
```

(or)

```
  fd=creat("/home/CSTCIS/sample.dat",mode);
```

When we are using the `creat()` function, it will open the file in read only mode.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem - this needed to be included among the flags: `O_CREAT`

Comment: Good effort. +1. If you don't mind, may I add this to my answer for future references?

Comment: Oh flip — I'm sorry I didn't spot that!  Obvious with hindsight…

Comment: No problem! Just relieved that stupid issue is past me.